# How to delete only consumed messages and how to show unconsumed messages in kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

We migrated a Project from ActiveMQ to Kafka.
In the past we wrote too many messages to many queues, and after consuming them, ActiveMQ deleted the consumed messages automatically. Only unconsumed message still in the Queues.
How can we implement this behavior in Kafka. We do not need the million consumed messages more. We need only to see the unconsumed messages.

I configured Kafka using the property log.retention.hours=1 to delete as fast as possible all messages which are consumed.

1. I have a topic crs.reporting.intern, I sent first of all 2 Messages to it and received them -> OK.

```
C:\Java\apache-kafka_2.13-3.3.1\bin\windows>kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group groupid.crs.reporting.intern
GROUP                        TOPIC                PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                   HOST            CLIENT-ID
groupid.crs.reporting.intern crs.reporting.intern 0          2               2               0               consumer-groupid.crs.reporting.intern-12-8fc98e12-d884-4c59-b41c-768721f98e51 /172.31.0.1     consumer-groupid.crs.reporting.intern-12
```

2. I stopped the consumer and as we see, there is no consumer who listens to the topic.

```
C:\Java\apache-kafka_2.13-3.3.1\bin\windows>kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group groupid.crs.reporting.intern
Consumer group 'groupid.crs.reporting.intern' has no active members.
GROUP                        TOPIC                PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
groupid.crs.reporting.intern crs.reporting.intern 0          2               2               0               -               -               -
```

3. I sent a third message to the topic, while no active consumer members.
   I still see the same result as in #2

```
C:\Java\apache-kafka_2.13-3.3.1\bin\windows>kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group groupid.crs.reporting.intern
Consumer group 'groupid.crs.reporting.intern' has no active members.
GROUP                        TOPIC                PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
groupid.crs.reporting.intern crs.reporting.intern 0          2               2               0               -               -               -
```

4. After I waited more than one houre, I started the consumers. Then I saw that all 3 Messages are deleted (2 which consumed and one which is not consumed yet)

```
C:\Java\apache-kafka_2.13-3.3.1\bin\windows>kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group groupid.crs.reporting.intern
GROUP                        TOPIC                PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                   HOST            CLIENT-ID
groupid.crs.reporting.intern crs.reporting.intern 0          2               2               0               consumer-groupid.crs.reporting.intern-60-60a4ffb9-7dea-44c6-a34e-7fb52ef61223 /172.31.0.1     consumer-groupid.crs.reporting.intern-60
```

Question to #3: How can we show the third unconsumed messages, before it can be deleted?

Question to #4: Is there a way to prevent deleting unconsumed messages?
In this case I expected, that only the first 2 consumed messages will be deleted and not the third one!

Although the third message still in the Kafka-Broker, it has been deleted:
[Data]-send->[Kafka Producer]-send->[**Kafka Broker**]<-Read-[Kafka Consumer]-Write->[Data Store]

Best regards,
Amjad

Answer (score 0):

Log segments (batches of messages) are deleted in kafka, not individual messages

The retention configuration is specific to closing of the log segments of a topic, where a segment size is 1GB of data, by default (3 events would be less than that),

Segment deletion doesn't know if data has been consumed or not, which is why all the data would have been deleted, and there's no way to prevent it without modifying the entire topic retention settings